# How to initialize get-only property C#

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

I have a class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string FullName { get; set; }
  public string Address{ get; }
}
```

How may I initialize an instance of this class and setup the 'Address' get-only property value?
I've tried with

```
var customer = new Customer 
{
  Id = 228,
  FullName = "Peter",
  Address = "Kreshatik",
};
```

but it it doesn't work.

Please, note that it's not my class and I have no ability to change anything there.

Comment: Does the class expose an address parameter on the constructor? Most likely it does. If so, just use that constructor instead of trying to specify the address value in an object initializer syntax.

Comment: To use this with the object initializer syntax, you'd need to be using C# 9 with [an init-only property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init): `public string Address { get; init; }`

Comment: The note that you can't modify the class should really be the first statement that you make.  That drastically impacts the solutions you can choose from.

Comment: Are you *supposed* to initialize instances of that class? If you cannot change it, did you get it from a 3rd party library? Perhaps there are ways to construct instances of it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//using System.Reflection;

var backingField = typeof(Customer).GetField("<Address>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

var customer = new Customer
{
    Id = 228,
    FullName = "Peter",
};

backingField.SetValue(customer, "Kreshatik");
```

If `backingField` is null you'll need to dig deeper with reflection to find it.

You can use `GetFields(...)` with the same flags to list them.

Once you figure all of that out, you can create an extension method:

```
public static class CustomerExtensions
{
    static FieldInfo addressField = typeof(Customer).GetField("<Address>k__BackingField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public static void SetAddress(this Customer customer, string address)
    {
        addressField.SetValue(customer, address);
    }
}
```

And use it as such:

```
var customer = new Customer
{
    Id = 228,
    FullName = "Peter",
};

customer.SetAddress("Kreshatik");
```

Comment: I would suggest never doing this in production code without first asking the owner of the `Customer` class to change their class definition first. Then ask their boss. Then ask their boss's boss. Only if all that fails do you try something like this.

Comment: @HereticMonkey obviously

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely agree with previous answer by @rfmodulator , under given circumstances reflection is the only possible solution. My steps to resolve this issue would be:

- check for parameters in all constructors
- check for public setter methods
- if you have access to source code, check for Address references (maybe the original purpose was something completely different and there is a reason why its setter is restricted)
- contact author
- reflection

Comment: Thanks. Depending on the circumstances, I might add "proxy class" somewhere in your list as well.